# logo':logo.image_tag(self) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_tag'

Tags: python, django, stack-overflow, attributeerror, nonetype

```
from . import models

def get_logo(request):
    logo=models.AppSetting.objects.first()
    data={
        'logo':logo.image_tag(self)
    }
    return data
```

`

This is my coding part here it is showing error. Can anyone please help me to fix it?

Comment: where you have defined `image_tag` method? I think, you want to send first object to template file, is it? Then, you must also use `render()` to render template.

Comment: Please share information of how you have declared your app settings.

Comment: It looks like you have no `AppSetting`: that corresponding table has no records.